# Render Properties as XMLAttributes in ASP.NET Web API response

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

Following is a class which represents a response of ASP.NET Web API service call.

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}

   public long FirstNameLastModified {get;set;}

   public string LastName {get;set;}

   public long LastNameLastModified {get;set;}

}
```

I am currently XmlSerializer instead of the default DataContractSerializer for reasons not related to this problem.

The response rendered here is of the form.

*The last modified values are timestamps and are related to the field.*

```
<User>
  <FirstName>Phill<FirstName>
  <FirstNameLastModified>12<FirstNameLastModified>
  <LastName>Haack<LastName>
  <LastNameLastModified>16<LastNameLastModified>
</User>
```

I want the XML to be rendered as

```
<User>
  <FirstName lastModified="12">Phill<FirstName>
  <LastName lastModified="16">Haack<LastName>
</User>
```

How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    [XmlText]
    public T Value;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int LastModified;
}

public class User
{
    public Foo<string> FirstName;
    public Foo<string> LastName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public class User
{
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public Name FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public Name LastName { get; set; }

}

public class Name
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("lastModified")]
    public long Modified { get; set; }
}
```